# Ios error while sorting an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray

When I try to sort an array, I got an exception like below:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key levels.'

To sort the arrays I use the following lines:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"levels" ascending:YES];
NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject: descriptor];

NSArray *reversedLevelIdArray = [levelsDictionary.allKeys sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

The `levelsDictionary.allKeys` contains the values like below:

> ( level2, level1 )

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the following codes to sort the array, instead of all of your other line of codes..

```
NSArray *reversedIdArray = [levelsDictionary.allKeys sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Sort Descriptor...

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject: descriptor];

    NSArray *reversedLevelIdArray = [levelsDictionary.allKeys sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

    NSLog(@"%@", reversedLevelIdArray);
```

You can use `@selector` to sort an array...

```
NSArray *resultArray = [levelsDictionary.allKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Using Comparator....

```
NSArray *resultArray = [levelsDictionary.allKeys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
    return obj2 > obj1;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sorting strings and they are ahving no property or method named `levels`. You should sort the values instead, like:

```
[levelsDictionary.allKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked you code, you are sorting the data and accessing the wrong key name of dictionary.

As you said that your levelDictionary contains the keys name as "level2", "level1", etc....

NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"levels" ascending:YES];

In this code you have used the key name as "levels" is wrong, because I think your dictionary "levelsDictionary" does not contains any key name as "levels".

Please try to use the proper key name and your error will resolve.